# Launch script from div which was added with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, android, html, innerhtml

I use javascript in my android app.

I need to add JS method of banner downloading to the existent div.

I do it like this :

```
function myFunction()
        {
         var b =  "<script async src=\"http:\/\/pagead2.googlesyndication.com\/pagead\/js\/adsbygoogle.js\"><\/script><!-- gg --><ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"     style=\"display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px\"     data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-7895107980112975\"     data-ad-slot=\"9640221435\"><\/ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});<\/script>";

            document.getElementById('detailsManager').innerHTML =b;
        };
```

Script content adds properly to the div, but doesn't launches.

I tried eval() but it didn't work for me. appendChild also didn't solve the task.

Need workable solution. Thanks.

Comment: If I remember right, You can not load google ads dynamically. You can not use innerHTML to add script tags, hence why that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't solve it like I wanted, but made it with script putting to the div BEFORE the page was loaded.